# MySQL join to colums in same table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table with IP flow data

SRC_IP | SRC_BW | DST_IP | DST_BW

For most of the IP addresses I care about, they will appear at one time or another in both columns but there are some that will only appear as a SRC or a DST.  I am trying to get a list of unique IPs and sum up their bandwidth (regardless of it was the source of the connection or the destination).

I currently have:

```
SELECT SRC_IP, SRC_BYTES, DST_BYTES, SRC_BYTES + IFNULL(DST_BYTES,0) as TOTAL_BYTES
FROM
    (SELECT INET6_NTOA(bro_conn.CONN_ORIGH) as SRC_IP, 
            SUM(bro_conn.CONN_ORIGIPBYTES) AS SRC_BYTES 
     FROM bro_conn GROUP BY SRC_IP) src
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT INET6_NTOA(bro_conn.CONN_RESPH) as DST_IP, 
            SUM(bro_conn.CONN_RESPIPBYTES) AS DST_BYTES 
     FROM bro_conn GROUP BY DST_IP) dst
ON src.SRC_IP = dst.DST_IP
```

My problem is that if an address only appears as a DST_IP, that it won't show up in the list.....thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` with *conditional aggreggation* and get rid of the `LEFT JOIN` operation:

```
SELECT IP AS SRC_IP,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'SRC' THEN BYTES ELSE 0 END) AS SRC_BYTES,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'DST' THEN BYTES ELSE 0 END) AS DST_BYTES,
       SUM(BYTES) AS TOTAL_BYTES
FROM (
  SELECT INET6_NTOA(bro_conn.CONN_ORIGH) as IP, 
         SUM(bro_conn.CONN_ORIGIPBYTES) AS BYTES,
         'SRC' AS Type 
  FROM bro_conn 
  GROUP BY SRC_IP

  UNION ALL

  SELECT INET6_NTOA(bro_conn.CONN_RESPH) as IP, 
         SUM(bro_conn.CONN_RESPIPBYTES) AS BYTES,
         'DST' AS Type  
  FROM bro_conn GROUP BY DST_IP) AS t
GROUP BY IP
```